# Attempting to use Kotlin Native with IntelliJ's base project but it won't compile

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-native

Hi I'm learning about Kotlin Native and as such I wanted to start with getting a project compiled and running, using IntelliJ's provided Kotlin Native files I get the following error: (Using: "gradle build")

```
 Execution failed for task ':compileKotlinMingw'.
 > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How do I get it working?

The build.gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.10'
}
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}
kotlin {
     targets {
         // For ARM, preset should be changed to presets.iosArm32 or presets.iosArm64
    // For Linux, preset should be changed to e.g. presets.linuxX64
    // For MacOS, preset should be changed to e.g. presets.macosX64
    fromPreset(presets.mingwX64, 'mingw')

    configure([mingw]) {
        // Comment to generate Kotlin/Native library (KLIB) instead of executable file:
        compilations.main.outputKinds('EXECUTABLE')
        // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
        compilations.main.entryPoint = 'sample.main'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    // Note: To enable common source sets please comment out 'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property
    // in gradle.properties file and re-import your project in IDE.
    mingwMain {
    }
    mingwTest {
    }
}
}

task runProgram {
def buildType = 'release' // Change to 'debug' to run application with debug symbols.
dependsOn "link${buildType.capitalize()}ExecutableMingw"
doLast {
    def programFile = kotlin.targets.mingw.compilations.main.getBinary('EXECUTABLE', buildType)
    exec {
        executable programFile
        args ''
    }
}
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
resolutionStrategy {
    eachPlugin {
        if (requested.id.id == "kotlin-multiplatform") {
            useModule("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-
plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'native_test'
```

SampleMingw.kt:

```
package sample

fun hello(): String = "Hello, Kotlin/Native!"

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    println(hello())
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileKotlinMingw'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:395)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.javaexec(DefaultFileOperations.java:225)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KonanCliRunner.run(KotlinNativeToolRunner.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinNativeCompile.compile(KotlinNativeTasks.kt:296)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 31 more
```

Added above stracktrace with gradle build --stacktrace

Comment: First off, you need to start with finding the actual error. There's a stacktrace somewhere

Comment: finished with non-zero exit value 1 isn't the actual error? Ok added stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

JDK must be 64-bit and either Java 8 or 9.

Comment: How do I tell it to use a 64-bit java jdk ? Because I have it installed